# Tooltips in .swf loaded with SWFLoader cause error #1009

Tags: apache-flex, tooltip, runtime-error, swfloader

I am working on a flex web project where a lot of the functionality is modular and the SWFs are loaded with SWFLoader. I've recently created a module which has tooltips on some elements and I was getting a runtime error #1009 when hovering over these elements to see the tooltip. If, instead of loading the SWF with SWFLoader at runtime, I instantiate it in the application directly, the tooltips work fine. Does anyone know why this is?

I'm using Flex SDK 4.5.1 because one of the libs I have to use doesn't work with later versions.

I've isolated the issue into a small example. Here's the code:

main mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               backgroundColor="#000000"
               creationComplete="onComplete(event);">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.SWFLoader;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            private function onComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {

                // Comment this block out to try without loading external swf
                var swfLoader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
                swfLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoadComplete);
                swfLoader.load("ExternalSWF.swf");

                // Uncomment this block to try without loading external swf ... Notice the tooltips suddenly work.. 
                /*var externalSwf:ExternalSWF = new ExternalSWF();
                this.addElement(externalSwf);*/
            }

            private function swfLoadComplete(event:Event):void {
                var externalSwf:ExternalSWF = (event.target as SWFLoader).content as ExternalSWF;
                this.addElement(externalSwf);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

ExternalSWF class (in flash builder 4.7, this is set to compile as a module):

```
package
{
    import spark.components.Button;
    import spark.components.VGroup;


    [Frame(factoryClass="ExternalSWF")]
    public class ExternalSWF extends VGroup
    {
        public function ExternalSWF()
        {
            super();
            var btn:Button = new Button();
            btn.label = "mouse over this";
            btn.toolTip = "moused over";

            this.addElement(btn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You said you are loading modules, so, they should be loaded with ModuleLoader or module related classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Zeus. That set me on the correct path and I was able to solve my problem.

Here's one solution:

main mxml AS code:

```
private var _info:IModuleInfo;

private function onComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {
    _info = ModuleManager.getModule("ExternalSWF.swf");
    _info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, modEventHandler);      
    _info.load(null, null, null, moduleFactory);
}

private function modEventHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void {
    var externalSwf:ExternalSWF  = _info.factory.create() as ExternalSWF;
    this.addElement(externalSwf);
}
```

ExternalSWF

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.Button;

    import spark.modules.Module;


    public class ExternalSWF extends Module
    {
        public function ExternalSWF()
        {
            super();
            var btn:Button = new Button();
            btn.label = "mouse over this";
            btn.toolTip = "moused over";

            this.addElement(btn);
        }
    }
}
```